# Teams Toolkit - Failed to provision 'App Service plan'

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, teams-toolkit

I'm trying to provision my bot to Azure but I'm getting the below error:
[Error] - code:Solution.ProvisionFailure, message: Failed to provision 'App Service plan'. Suggestions: Please check log in output channel and try to fix this issue.

No details in the output channel.
Any idea why that's happening? I just used the default project configuration, didn't change a thing.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like behind the scenes this is trying to provision this kind of resource in Azure. Do you have an Azure subscription?

Comment: Can you double check if you missed out on any step specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/first-app-bot?tabs=vscode#deploy-your-app-to-azure? Also, can you try with a different subscription(if available) and see if you are able to provision successfully?

Comment: It seems to have an active azure subscription to provide app subscription plan.

Comment: Thank you guys, I followed all steps in Microsoft's doc and our subscription is valid, but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of Teams Toolkit in Microsoft, thanks for trying our new Toolkit. According to this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/first-app-bot?tabs=vscode#deploy-your-app-to-azure, when you provision to Azure resource, have you been asked to login your Azure account by browser? Have you ever seen the confirm window that saying "The Teams Toolkit will provision resources under xxx (Azure account) with xxx (subscription)"? If yes, please check if the Azure account and subscription is correct.

One update is that in Teams Toolkit v2.2.0, we add one feature to provide more error details. If you upgrade the VSCode extension, you can check the OUTPUT channel (select "Teams Toolkit" channel) to see more details as below.
[image]